# namespace issue when using libgazebo_ros2_control

Tags: ros2, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11, namespace, gazebo-ros2-control

I am launching a robot_state_publisher from within a namespace 'zray'. I get confirmation the node is running and I see

"[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1709760080.001380149] [zray.robot_state_publisher]: got segment zray/base_link"

on the terminal (plus more of the same with the remaining links)

In my xacro file, within a gazebo tag, I am including the libgazebo_ros2_control plugin

```
<plugin name="$(arg namespace)_gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
          <parameters namespace="$(arg namespace)">$(find zray_description)/config/controller_configuration.yaml</parameters>
</plugin>
```

When I spawn the robot into the gazebo simulation, I get the error
"[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1709760089.957270373] [zray_gazebo_ros2_control]: robot_state_publisher service not available, waiting again..."

I think the issue may be due to my namespace. Calling ros2 node list I see

/zray_gazebo_ros2_control (not /zray/zray_gazebo_ros2_control)

The robot state publisher is there, and when I look at the node info I see

```
ros2 node info /zray/robot_state_publisher 
/zray/robot_state_publisher
  Subscribers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /zray/joint_states: sensor_msgs/msg/JointState
  Publishers:
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
    /tf: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
    /tf_static: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
    /zray/robot_description: std_msgs/msg/String
  Service Servers:
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /zray/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
  Service Clients:

  Action Servers:

  Action Clients:
```

How do I get the gazebo_ros2_control plugin to find the robot_state_publisher service? I have tried putting

```
<ros>
    <remap from="/robot_description" to="/zray/robot_description"/>
</ros>
```

within the plugin tags to no effect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which ROS version do you use?

Comment: @christophfroehlich I am using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo 11.  I initially tried '<plugin name="$(arg namespace)_gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
          $(find zray_description)/config/controller_configuration.yaml</parameters>
</plugin> ' before adding namespace in the parameters tag but I got the same results. Ive been stuck here for a few days, any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PR](https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/pull/181) fixing namespacing for gazebo_ros2_control (but for rolling). You will also find a documentation of how to configure the namespace inside the PR.

Can you compile [this branch](https://github.com/DoppiaEffe94/gazebo_ros2_control/tree/namespace_issue_humble) from source and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: Im making progress. I compiled the branch you linked to. I added the remapping as suggested in the PR and I got "parser error Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '--param robot_description" To fix this I added <robot_param>zray/robot_description</robot_param>
          <robot_param_node>zray/robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node> (namespace hard coded for now). I am still getting the error, but the robot state publisher is now within the namespace "[zray.gazebo_ros2_control]: zray/robot_state_publisher service not available". I can see the service using ros2 service list. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I never used the namespacing within gazebo and would need to analyze that too. Could you please summarize your configuration and write your problem in the linked PR? Overall it would be great to add a working example to gazebo_ros2_control_demos, if you'd like to contribute to the package.

Comment: I would live to contribute any way I can. Ill do my best to summarize the problem, let me know if I need to add more or different details. Thanks

Comment: Nice to hear. I think a demo with two namespaced robots would be very valuable. For example, the diff_drive and tricycle robot already included in the gazebo_ros2_control_demos, but launched at once with correct namespaces set. You can setup that locally, and then make a PR targeting the master branch of gazebo_ros2_control. According to the reported issues, it should not work with the released version but with the code from the linke PR above.